# Applicative functors analysis

Tags: haskell, static-analysis, functor, applicative

I've been trying to learn about static analysis of applicative functors. Many sources say that an advantage of using them over monads is the susceptibility to static analysis.

However, the only [example](http://gergo.erdi.hu/blog/2012-12-01-static_analysis_with_applicatives/) I can find of actually performing static analysis is too complicated for me to understand. Are there any simpler examples of this?

Specifically, I want to know if I can performing static analysis on recursive applications.    For example, something like:

```
y = f <$> x <*> y <*> z
```

When analyzing the above code, is it possible to detect that it is recursive on y? Or does referential transparency still prevent this from being possible?

Comment: One library that takes advantage of being able to statically analyze `Applicative` functors at runtime is [optparse-applicative](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative).  Every `Parser a` can be executed to construct something that parses commandline options into an `a`, or it can be analyzed to extract the commandline help without actually running the parser.  The source is actually pretty readable and is a nice introduction to the technique.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Applicative functors allow static analysis at runtime. This is better explained by a simpler example.

Imagine you want to calculate a value, but want to track what dependencies that value has. Eg you may use `IO a` to calculate the value, and have a list of `Strings` for the dependencies:

```
data Input a = Input { dependencies :: [String], runInput :: IO a }
```

Now we can easily make this an instance of `Functor` and `Applicative`. The functor instance is trivial. As it doesn't introduce any new dependencies, you just need to map over the `runInput` value:

```
instance Functor (Input) where
  fmap f (Input deps runInput) = Input deps (fmap f runInput)
```

The `Applicative` instance is more complicated. the `pure` function will just return a value with no dependencies. The `<*>` combiner will concat the two list of dependencies (removing duplicates), and combine the two actions:

```
instance Applicative Input where
  pure = Input [] . return

  (Input deps1 getF) <*> (Input deps2 runInput) = Input (nub $ deps1 ++ deps2) (getF <*> runInput)
```

With that, we can also make an `Input a` an instance of Num if `Num a`:

```
instance (Num a) => Num (Input a) where
  (+) = liftA2 (+)
  (*) = liftA2 (*)
  abs = liftA abs
  signum = liftA signum
  fromInteger = pure . fromInteger
```

Nexts, lets make a couple of Inputs:

```
getTime :: Input UTCTime
getTime = Input { dependencies = ["Time"], runInput = getCurrentTime }

-- | Ideally this would fetch it from somewhere
stockPriceOf :: String -> Input Double
stockPriceOf stock = Input { dependencies = ["Stock ( " ++ stock ++ " )"], runInput = action } where
  action = case stock of
    "Apple" -> return 500
    "Toyota" -> return 20
```

Finally, lets make a value that uses some inputs:

```
portfolioValue :: Input Double
portfolioValue = stockPriceOf "Apple" * 10 + stockPriceOf "Toyota" * 20
```

This is a pretty cool value. Firstly, we can find the dependencies of `portfolioValue` as a pure value:

```
> :t dependencies portfolioValue
dependencies portfolioValue :: [String]
> dependencies portfolioValue
["Stock ( Apple )","Stock ( Toyota )"]
```

That is the static analysis that `Applicative` allows - we know the dependencies without having to execute the action.

We can still get the value of the action though:

```
> runInput portfolioValue >>= print
5400.0
```

---

Now, why can't we do the same with `Monad`? The reason is `Monad` can express choice, in that one action can determine what the next action will be.

Imagine there was a `Monad` interface for `Input`, and you had the following code:

```
mostPopularStock :: Input String
mostPopularStock = Input { dependencies ["Popular Stock"], getInput = readFromWebMostPopularStock }

newPortfolio = do
  stock <- mostPopularStock
  stockPriceOf "Apple" * 40 + stockPriceOf stock * 10
```

Now, how can we calculate the dependencies of `newPortolio`? It turns out we can't do it without using IO! It will depend on the most popular stock, and the only way to know is to run the IO action. Therefore it isn't possible to statically track dependencies when the type uses Monad, but completely possible with just Applicative. This is a good example of why often less power means more useful - as Applicative doesn't allow choice, dependencies can be calculated statically.

---

Edit: With regards to the checking if `y` is recursive on itself, such a check is possible with applicative functors if you are willing to annotate your function names.

```
data TrackedComp a = TrackedComp { deps :: [String],  recursive :: Bool, run :: a}

instance (Show a) => Show (TrackedComp a) where
  show comp = "TrackedComp " ++ show (run comp)

instance Functor (TrackedComp) where
  fmap f (TrackedComp deps rec1 run) = TrackedComp deps rec1 (f run)

instance Applicative TrackedComp where
  pure = TrackedComp [] False

  (TrackedComp deps1 rec1 getF) <*> (TrackedComp deps2 rec2 value) =
    TrackedComp (combine deps1 deps2) (rec1 || rec2) (getF value)

-- | combine [1,1,1] [2,2,2] = [1,2,1,2,1,2]
combine :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
combine x [] = x
combine [] y = y
combine (x:xs) (y:ys) = x : y : combine xs ys

instance (Num a) => Num (TrackedComp a) where
  (+) = liftA2 (+)
  (*) = liftA2 (*)
  abs = liftA abs
  signum = liftA signum
  fromInteger = pure . fromInteger

newComp :: String -> TrackedComp a -> TrackedComp a
newComp name tracked = TrackedComp (name : deps tracked) isRecursive (run tracked) where
   isRecursive = (name `elem` deps tracked) || recursive tracked 


y :: TrackedComp [Int]
y = newComp "y" $ liftA2 (:) x z

x :: TrackedComp Int
x = newComp "x" $ 38

z :: TrackedComp [Int]
z = newComp "z" $ liftA2 (:) 3 y

> recursive x
False
> recursive y
True
> take 10 $ run y
[38,3,38,3,38,3,38,3,38,3]
```

Comment: This is a great answer, but doesn't quite make it to answering the original guy's questions; specifically: no, you can't observe that `y` is recursive on itself (except perhaps by poking at some GHC-specific APIs), and yes, that's because of referential transparency.

Comment: @aurickQ: Thats great! As Daniel pointed out, I didn't answer the part about checking if `y` is recursive, I've added another part to the question about this.

Comment: I know what you mean, but the phrase "static analysis at runtime" just sounds really funny. It's almost self-contradictory.

Comment: @TikhonJelvis I also dislike that phrasing, but I couldn't think of a better way of describing it :(

Answer (score 3):

Yes, applicative functors allow more analysis than monads.  But no, you can't observe the recursion.  I've written a paper about parsing which explains the problem in detail:

https://lirias.kuleuven.be/bitstream/123456789/352570/1/gc-jfp.pdf

The paper then discusses an alternative encoding of recursion which does allow analysis and has some other advantages and some downsides.  Other related work is:

https://lirias.kuleuven.be/bitstream/123456789/376843/1/p97-devriese.pdf

And more related work can be found in the related work sections of those papers...